# How do I make it so that java stops converting my char(s) to other numerical values

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, char, indexoutofboundsexception

For this project, we have to make a 2D char array that mimics the seats on a plane(Ex: 1 A B C D
2 A B C D), I'm using a scanner to ask the user for the seat that they want to reserve so I take the seat they gave me (Ex: 2A) when I print the array it will show seat 2A as an 'X'. However, when I use charAt to grab the "2A" from the user it is turning the values from the char to a number, say 50 or 68 which in turn is making me have an out of bounds error when I try to set the array index to 'X'.

```
System.out.println("These seats above are all available seats. Enter which seat you would" +
                " like to reserve(ex: 1A)");
        userSeatChoice = keyboard.nextLine();
        int seatOne = userSeatChoice.charAt(0);
        char seatTwo = userSeatChoice.charAt(1);

        int colResponse = 0;


        if (seatTwo == 'A')
        {
            colResponse = '1';
        } else if (seatTwo == 'B') {
            colResponse = '2';
        } else if (seatTwo == 'C') {
            colResponse = '3';
        } else if (seatTwo == 'D') {
            colResponse = '4';
        }

        if (!(plan[seatOne][colResponse] == 'X')) {
            plan[seatOne][colResponse] = 'X';
        }else {
            System.out.println("Sorry this seat is already taken.");
        }
        printSeats(plan);
```

Im receiving the out of bounds index here (plan[seatOne][colResponse] = 'X';)
I just want to know a solution or alternate code to make this work

Comment: What is the value of `plan`? Why are you trying to use `char` as an array index? I suggest you use an `int` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the ASCII value of your character with

```
int seatOne = userSeatChoice.charAt(0);
```

Instead, parse it. Like,

```
int seatOne = Character.digit(userSeatChoice.charAt(0), 10);
```

**or**

```
int seatOne = userSeatChoice.charAt(0) - '0';
```